# Bash variable expansion inside string (makefile)

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to make a makefile script, which extracts number of packets in pcap file using tcpreplay command and other tools. Number of packets is then forwarded to test files using additional gcc flags.

```
    tcpreplay = "/usr/bin/tcpreplay --topspeed --intf1=lo "${PWD}"/to/file.pcap | sed -n 5p | cut -d' ' -f11"
    # get number of packet in PCAP
    PKT_NUM = `eval ${tcpreplay}`
    TEST_CFLAGS = -DPKT_NUM=$(PKT_NUM)
    #print VAR cmd 
    print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)
```

Above command does not work, even though content of tcpreplay is valid, when executed in terminal. I have also found out that it causes this part:

```
"${PWD}"/to/file.pcap
```

when exchanged with:

```
/absolute/path/to/file.pcap
```

it works as expected.

So how can be fixed script with $PWD approach?

Comment: Please remove spaces before and after '=' sign and try again.

Comment: Do not only try again after removing the spaces but also report back here about the results ;-)

Comment: I have deleted spaces and also checked code with http://shellcheck.net, but problem still remains.

Comment: Does the path to your working directory by any means contain spaces? Because ${PWD} is not quoted.

Comment: No it does not, I think problem must be somewhere else, because with absolute path everything works great and constant PKT_NUM is defined in my executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but your Makefile will be clearer if you get the shell stuff out of the way first.  In GNU make, use the shell function to evaluate your shell code.  Also, GNU make defines PWD for you.  So:

```
tcpreplay = /usr/bin/tcpreplay --topspeed --intf1=lo $(PWD)/to/file.pcap 

# get number of packet in PCAP
PKT_NUM = $(shell $(tcprelay) | sed -n 5p | cut -d' ' -f11)
TEST_CFLAGS = -DPKT_NUM=$(PKT_NUM)
```

If that doesn't do what you want, you can see things better without the shell function:

```
PKT_NUM = $$( $(tcprelay) | sed -n 5p | cut -d' ' -f11 )
```

I don't understand the intent of what you're doing with the `print-%` rule, but perhaps that will get you going.

Answer (score 0):

The first two statement

```
tcpreplay="/usr/bin/tcpreplay --topspeed --intf1=lo "${PWD}"/to/file.pcap | sed -n 5p | cut -d' ' -f11"
PKT_NUM=`eval ${tcpreplay}`
```

look pretty much ok and the shell should really resolve the ${PWD}. I guess it results in an int being assigned to PKT_NUM? However

```
TEST_CFLAGS=-DPKT_NUM=$(PKT_NUM)
```

looks a bit strange because it seems you want to execute the int and assign it to TEST_CFLAGS?

Could you paste the actual output of your command? I cannot reproduce it because I don't have "tcpreplay".

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't mentioned it's a makefile. When I run 
make print-PKT_NUM it results with:
PKT_NUM = 9975 , which is correct. Then I need provide this part to gcc compiler, which compiles packet test. In above command my compiler is raising error that it did not received any -DPKT_NUM definition through gcc command line. I have really simplified this, there are also SUBDIR make calls, but it should not matter because with absolute path it works perfect.

Comment: the result of command `eval ${tcpreplay}` parses output of tcpreplay and gives only number of attempted packets `NUMBER`

Comment: @Sach The fact that it is a Makefile is pretty relevant. Makefiles are not shell scripts.

Comment: @chepner, yeah my bad I was working also on bash script and get it confused, sorry.